# Exempt a specific attribute from been selected in Laravel Mysql Json Column

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, database

I am trying to return results of a specific table in Laravel while hiding a specific attribute from the returned SQL results.

Part of the JSON response is as shown

```
...
"custom_filters": [
 {
     "question_type": "single",
     "question": "How long have you been an influencer",
     "answer": 1
 },
 {
     "question_type": "choice",
     "question": "Have you ever went viral?",
     "choices": [
         "yes",
         "no"
     ],
     "answer": "yes"
 },
 {
     "question_type": "single",
     "question": "How many followers do you have on Instagram",
     "answer": 12000
 }
],
...
```

Expected Output

```
...
"custom_filters": [
    {
        "question_type": "single",
        "question": "How long have you been an influencer",
    },
    {
        "question_type": "choice",
        "question": "Have you ever went viral?",
        "choices": [
            "yes",
            "no"
        ]
      },
    {
        "question_type": "single",
        "question": "How many followers do you have on Instagram"
    }
],
...
```

I want the answer part of the JSON OBJECT to be hidden/removed in the final output as shown above. I know i could get the results from my Eloquent model and filter the results accordingly discarding the `answer` part. but I feel like there is a better way of doing this.

by the way here is the code for fetching the results

```
$posts = Posts::where('status', 'published')->orderBy('post_id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Posts::where('status', 'published')->orderBy('post_id', 'desc')->whereJsonContains('json_data', [['custom_filters' => ['answer' => 'yes']]])->get()
```

Comment: This Query would not give out the expected output, as you can see the field `answer` has dynamic content, it can be a digit or a string. See my expected output.